# Добавление и удаление активного класса

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У меня есть код, который доабвляет актив на ссылки при клике.Но мне надо чтоб в каждой строке мог быть только один активный класс, и при клике на другую ссылку предыдущий убирался,как это можно делать сейчас
[image: Пример]

```js
$(function() {
  $(".menu-item").click(function() {

    if ($('.menu-item a').is('.active-picker')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active-picker')
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("active-picker");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marketgroups hidden">
  <div class="menu-picker d-flex align-items-center gray-400">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center ">
        <div class="menu-title">Code1</div>
        <div class="w-100">
          <ul class="d-flex justify-content-center marketgroups-link">
            <li class="menu-item ">
              <a href="#">JEDMXP</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="#">JFKMXP</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="#">JFKPRG</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-picker flightselector hidden gray-300">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center ">
      <div class="menu-title">Code2</div>
      <div class="w-100">
        <ul class="d-flex justify-content-center flightselector-link">
          <li class="menu-item ">
            <a href="#">4291TLVPRG</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">5288PRGTLV</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">4290PRGTLV</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">4291TLVPRG</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: использование siblings() обращается к соседним элементам

Comment: а можешь примерно написать, как это должно выглядеть

Comment: попробуйте вместо `$(this).removeClass('active-picker')` поставить  `$('.menu-item a').removeClass('active-picker')`

Comment: не помогло, вообще не добавляется

Comment: `$(this).parent('ul').find('.menu-item.active-picker').removeClass('active-picker'); $(this).addClass('active-picker');` Таких и подобных этому вопросов задано было уже не один [десяток](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=site%3Aru.stackoverflow.com%20javascript%20Добавление%20и%20удаление%20активного%20класса).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удаляешь у всех у которых есть и добавляешь только элементу по которому кликаешь.

```
$(".menu-item").click(function() {
    $('.menu-item a.active-picker').removeClass('active-picker');
    $(this).addClass("active-picker");
})
```

По хорошему еще проверка нужна

```
$(".menu-item").click(function() {
    if(!$(this).is('.active-picker')) {
        $('.menu-item a').removeClass('active-picker');
        $(this).addClass("active-picker");
    }
})
```